# Why isn't this python string comparison working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-comparison

I have the following comparison in python:

```
"LC08_L1TP_215068_20151114_20170402_01_T1_B1"=="LC08*_B[1-7]"
```

Which should return True but doesn't. Does anyone know what the problem is, and how to solve it?

Comment: You need to use regex. Look at the `re` module

Comment: I don't get your logic, why would these two string be equal?

Comment: @abccd Not equal, but if this comparation can be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex. This can be done with the `re` module. In Python strings are equal only if every character is the same, not with pattern matching. I believe what you are trying to achieve is:

```
import re

print(re.match("LC08[^B]*_B[1-7]", "LC08_L1TP_215068_20151114_20170402_01_T1_B1") != None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at `re` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

def main():
    mystring = 'LC08_L1TP_215068_20151114_20170402_01_T1_B1'
    m = re.search('^LC08_.*B\d{1,7}', mystring)
    print(m != None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```